# How to write mock test for method with logger?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, mockito

I have the following interface:

```
public interface SomeProcessor<T> {
    void process(Stream<T> someStream);


    default <R> R someMap(Function<T, R> function,
                             T message,
                             Logger log) {
        try {
            return function.apply(message);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("Mapping error for message => {}", message, exception);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And want to cover log part of the method by mock test but unfortunately it always fails.
Now I have the following test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SomeProcessorTest<T> implements SomeProcessor<T> {

    @Mock
    private Logger mockLogger;

    @Override
    public void process(Stream<T> someStream) {
    }

    @Override
    public <R> R someMap(Function<T, R> function, T message, Logger log) {
        try {
            return function.apply(message);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("Mapping error for message => {}", message, exception);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testWithException() {

        SomeProcessor<String> processor = new SomeProcessor <String>() {
            @Override
            public void process(Stream<String> someStream) {
            }

            @Override
            public <R> R someMap(Function<String, R> function, String message, Logger log) {
                throw new RuntimeException("test exception");
            }
        };

        Function<String, Integer> function = Integer::parseInt;
        String message = "123";
        assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> processor.someMap(function, message, mockLogger));

        ArgumentCaptor<String> someCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<Throwable> exceptionCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Throwable.class);
        verify(mockLogger).error(eq("Mapping error for message => {}"), eq(message), any(RuntimeException.class));
        assertEquals("Mapping error for message => {}", someCaptor.getValue());
        assertTrue(exceptionCaptor.getValue() instanceof RuntimeException);
    }}
```

But I always see errors related to `Wanted but not invoked: mockLogger.error...`
and I cannot cover the following lines in my interface

```
catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error("Mapping error for message => {}", message, exception);
            return null;
```

What should I change im my mock test to cover these lines and not catching an error?
Give me a piece of advice please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of mixed up things in your code and the rationale behind it is not clear at first glance. The problem with `mockLogger.error` not being called has its source in the fact that you're overriding the default implementation of the `someMap` method from the interface within the anonymous class inside your test method:

```java
@Override
public <R> R someMap(Function<String, R> function, String message, Logger log) {
    throw new RuntimeException("test exception");
}
```

Because of that the code you're trying to test is not called at all. Instead, you should call `super.someMap(...)` from your anonymous class to invoke the actual interface method default implementation.

When you do that though, the assertion of `RuntimeException` being thrown will fail as the original method consumes the exception and returns `null` - no exception is thrown.

Removing the assertion of throwing an exception still would not make the test pass, because the function you're testing (`Integer::parseInt`) should work fine for the `message` you're providing (`"123"`), so the `catch` block will not be executed as no exception is thrown. To solve that you should pass a message value that would cause parsing failure - not a number (e.g. `"abc"`).

Finally - I don't understand why your class implements `SomeProcessor<T>`, but that seems to be redundant and may be removed.